# Personalization with Target Groups - Customer Characteristic

Tags: 2013, content-delivery, personalization

I want my component presentation to be personalized depending on a customer characteristic (customerType). We show different component presentations depending different customerType accessing to the page. customerType will come from java backend logic(as of now I am bringing from URL request parameters).
I am done with following steps:-
Create Target Group.
Add Target group with a component presentation on the page.

condition will be used by Tridion CD APIs.
Published page has my Component Presentation wrapped with  tag below :-

```
        <div>
<tridion:TargetGroup itemURI="tcm:100-1000000-64">
    <tridion:Conditions negate="false" operator="AND">
    <tridion:Conditions negate="false" operator="OR">
    <tridion:Conditions negate="false" operator="AND">
    <tridion:Condition type="CustomerCharacteristic" operator="=" negate="false" name="customerType" value="1"/>
    <tridion:Condition type="CustomerCharacteristic" operator="=" negate="false" name="customerType" value="0"/>
    </tridion:Conditions>
    </tridion:Conditions>
    </tridion:Conditions>
    <form:form action="****" method="post" commandName="**"  id="location">
    <input type="submit" value="AppLoc" id="AppLoc" style="display:none;" />
    <div class="" role="main">
      <table>
        <tr>
             <td >Branch</td>
             <td ><div>abc</div></td>
          </tr
      </table>
     </div>
    </form:form>
    </tridion:TargetGroup>
</div>
```

What I am able to find is CD API  com.tridion.personalization  and below is my code

```
    <%@ page import="com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPPage,
    com.tridion.personalization.CustomerCharacteristics,
    com.tridion.user.User"%>

    <%
    JSPPage waiPage = new JSPPage(pageContext, "tcm:1-1-64");
    CustomerCharacteristics customerCharacteristics = new CustomerCharacteristics(waiPage.getUser());
    String custT = request.getParameter("customerType");
    customerCharacteristics.setValue("customerType", custT);
    customerCharacteristics.executeUpdate();


      %>
    <html>
      <head></head><body>
        <hr color="#000000" /> <center>

    <h3><%="- " + customerCharacteristics.getValue("customerType")%> </h3>
    <h3><%="----  :" + waiPage.getUser()%> </h3>

    <div>
<!-- Below conditions updated ad per the suggestion provided by Bjørn van Dommelen -->
    <tridion:TargetGroup itemURI="tcm:159-164141-64">
    <tridion:Conditions negate="false" operator="AND">
    <tridion:Condition type="CustomerCharacteristic" operator="=" negate="true" name="customerType" value="2"/>
    </tridion:Conditions> 
        <div class="" role="main">
          <table>
            <tr>
                 <td >Branch</td>
                 <td ><div>abc</div></td>
              </tr
          </table>
         </div>   
        </tridion:TargetGroup>
    </div>
      </center>
      </body>
      </html>`
```

I am getting my entries in CUSTOMER_CHARACTERISTICS and User table in Broker database. I think only think left now is condition.

Comment: are you using dd4t?

Comment: No Raj simple JSP..

Comment: @RajKumar  Thanks for the URLs I am able to proceed with the code and I have updated my question with my progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently used Target group on DXA, Please use following links to understand it better.

- setup - http://blog.building-blocks.com/technical-tips/how-to-setup-sdl-tridion-profiling-personalisation
- end to end example http://rajmittal.blogspot.in/2015/08/profiling-and-personalization-using.html
- JSP example https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/b/weblog/archive/2008/12/16/how-to-configure-personalization-and-profilingg

Comment: Documentation is **ContentDeliveryReferenceGuide_51SP4.pdf**  and **SDL Tridion R5 Content Delivery Project Planning Guide 5.3 SP1_tcm89-17676.pdf** and **SDL Tridion R5 Templating Manual 5.3 SP1_tcm89-17683.pdf**  Thanks @RajKumar

Answer (score 0):

1) Your conditions appear bogus. You're doing an AND of an OR of an AND of two complementary conditions (User type cannot be both 1 and 0 at the same time). In your scenario i'd expect the following (but depends on business requirements ofc):

```
<tridion:Conditions negate="false" operator="OR">
  <tridion:Condition type="CustomerCharacteristic" operator="=" negate="false" name="customerType" value="1"/>
  <tridion:Condition type="CustomerCharacteristic" operator="=" negate="false" name="customerType" value="0"/>
</tridion:Conditions>
```

2) You're not using a dynamic component presentation. I'm pretty a WAI tracking tag must be used like so:

```
<tridion:TargetGroup itemURI="tcm:1-2-64">
  <tridion:Conditions negate="false" operator="OR">
    One or more condition tags go here
  </tridion:Conditions>
  <tridion:ComponentPresentation componentUri="tcm:1-3" templateUri="tcm:1-4-32" />
</tridion:TargetGroup>
```

This means your component presentation must be a statically assembled dynamic component presentation and not a statically embedded one like you are showing.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the post , even if I keep only one condition I still get 3 <tridion:Conditions tags. This is automatically added while publishing and I have rechecked my PT code it is only having 1 time TBB added - "Default Finish Actions". Coming Back to Component presentation I am using a CT which is  "published Embedded on Page". Also I am only using characteristics in Target group and no Tracking. My question here will be I can used only characteristics for personalization and through code I can set the characteristics and Can we use it on CP which I am using?

Comment: My business case is like I have to show hide CP based on customerType coming from backend or URL. So you mean yo say I should make my CT  as - "Published as dynamic component"   also I am not using categories in my schema as I believe it only in case of tracking which I am not doing.

Answer (score 0):

Things mentioned above in my question is working perfectly, only issue was my **CD_tags.tld** now not configured properly and neither it was giving any logs.
I changed the  element, double checked the **Web.xml** and rebuild/ redeployed the application. It worked.